# Regex change all vowels to a corresponding number

Tags: regex

How, using regex, can I change all vowels with a value corresponding to the character's (vowel's) index in the alphabet?

I am attempting to rename files

Vowels/values:

```
a change to 1
e change to 5
i change to 9
o change to 15
u change to 20
```

Comment: aeiou are vowels

Comment: do you want to change vowels or consonants ?

Comment: he wishes to change vowels

Comment: All of the numbers except 20 seem to correspond to the letter's position in the alphabet (u would be 21). Is this a principle you forgot to mention in the question, or should we just assume mapping to arbitrary numbers?

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it only by regex, although you can do it in the programming language you are using,

```js
let str = 'bcaeiough';

str = str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(match){
    let sub = match.charCodeAt(0)-96;
    return sub.toString();
})
console.log(str);
```